# How to develop responsive page in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want create a page using xamarin in  landscape and portrait mode, am done in portrait mode, but in landscape mode the design changing.I have no idea how to fix it.I am tried different layout also, but that doesn't work for me.

Here is my design
[image]

XAML

```
<RelativeLayout x:Name="outer_Layout" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    BackgroundColor="#14C2F4" >
        <AbsoluteLayout  RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=50}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
                          BackgroundColor="#14C2F4">
            <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,0.13"
               BackgroundColor="#14C2F4"
               HasShadow="True"                   
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <Image Source="hambuger" Aspect="AspectFill"
                       WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="20"
                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                       VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
            </Frame>

            <Frame x:Name="frm_Search"
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0.15,1,0.1"
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       MinimumHeightRequest="30"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       Padding="10,0,10,0"  BorderColor="White"
                       BackgroundColor="#14C2F4" CornerRadius="0"
                       HasShadow="False" Margin="20,10,20,10">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="search_white" IsVisible="False"
                           HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20"
                          />
                    <local:CustomEntry x:Name="ent_Search" Placeholder="Search..." 
                                       TextColor="White"
                                       PlaceholderColor="White"
                                       FontSize="15"
                                       Text="David Ro"
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"                                          
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <ListView x:Name="lv_Favorites" ItemsSource="{Binding _list}"  
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None"
                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0.62,1,0.64"
                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="#14C2F4" 
                      RowHeight="70"
                      Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                            Margin="5"
                                            Padding="0">


                                <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White"
                                                 Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="25,2,5,2">
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="-10,5,10,0">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Location}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <local:CustomButton 
                                            Text="FOLLOW"
                                            TextColor="White"
                                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                            CustomBackgroundColor="#14C2F4"
                                            CustomBorderRadius="5"
                                            Padding="10,0,10,0"
                                            Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <ci:CircleImage Source="{Binding ImageName}" Aspect="AspectFit"
                                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,0.3,1"
                                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                                Margin="-10,0,0,0"
                                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            </AbsoluteLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>

        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=-55}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0,Constant=60}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1}">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                    
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackLayout x:Name="stack_Home" Spacing="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Image x:Name="img_home" HeightRequest="30" Source="home_gray"/>
                <Label Text="Home" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Home_Tapped"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout x:Name="stack_favorites" Spacing="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Image x:Name="img_favorites" HeightRequest="30" Source="logo"/>
                <Label Text="Favorites" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Favorites_Tapped"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And also when the size of the rounded image changed, the design also changing.How Can I manage it.

Please Help me..

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find multiple blogs of developers where they explain how to handle orientation change in Xamarin.Forms,

What you need to do is check these blogs understand them and change things accordingly:

I would suggest these blogs:

- https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/09/24/xamarin-forms-orientation-changes/
- https://www.wintellect.com/responding-to-orientation-changes-in-xamarin-forms/
- https://www.jimbobbennett.io/orientation-with-xamarin-forms/
- https://sellsbrothers.com/13740

Revert in case of queries

Good luck.